# Use react-native-firebase/auth OAuth provider to auth Azure AD credential

Tags: react-native, oauth, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

I am developing a mobile with react-native (react-native-firebase/auth) and using Firebase Auth to manage user login.  In the beginning, I only use the email/password to auth users and work nice.

Now I would like to let users use Azure AD.  Since react-native-firebase/auth does not support Microsoft account at this moment, so I use react-native-app-auth.  Afterwards, use the Microsoft credential to auth the Firebase user and link them together.

```js
const result = await authorize(config);
const credential = auth.OAuthProvider.credential(
  result.idToken,
  result.accessToken,
);
const userCredential = await auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
```

When calling the signInWithCredential, it throw an error : [auth/internal-error].

Currently, I have backend user profile like to a Firebase user account.  I don't want to complicate the backend to have multiple auth methods.  Ideally, it can be done at the Firebase would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm stuck on the same thing.

Comment: I have raised this with `react-native-firebase` maintainers here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4731

Comment: @Dave, finally, we use the Microsoft OAuth token to generate a custom token at the backend and continue the auth flow.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond. That’s where we ended up going as well.

Comment: Bit of a necro, but to anyone who came here looking for the same thing I did, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69671161/how-do-i-use-saml-to-authenticate-a-user-in-firebase-under-react-native-expo/69671162#69671162) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you have to use a custom token.

> Unlike other OAuth providers supported by Firebase such as Google, Facebook, and Twitter, where sign-in can directly be achieved with OAuth access token based credentials, Firebase Auth does not support the same capability for providers such as Microsoft due to the inability of the Firebase Auth server to verify the audience of Microsoft OAuth access tokens.
>
> If these providers are required to be used in unsupported environments, a third party OAuth library and [Firebase custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) would need to be used.
>
> source: [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#expandable-2)