# 'Invalid credential or provider ID' error when passing Azure token to Firebase in React Native

Tags: firebase, azure, react-native

I am building a React Native app and testing with a development build in iOS simulator. I use Firebase Auth to manage login etc and have got this to work for simple email/password login.

However, I am struggling to implement Microsoft Azure SSO. I am able to retrieve tokens from Microsoft, but when these credentials are submitted to Firebase they are returned with a `auth/invalid-credential-or-provider-id` error.

Here is my code:

```
// Endpoint
    const discovery = useAutoDiscovery(
        'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0',
    );

    let redirectUri = null
    
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        redirectUri = 'msauth.com.<my app's address>://auth'
    }
    else if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        redirectUri = 'msauth://com.<my app's address>/2jmj7l5rSw0yVb%2FvlWAYkK%2FYBwk%3D'
    }


    const clientId = '<my app's client id>';
// Request
    const [request, , promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
        {
        clientId,
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
        redirectUri,
        },
        discovery,
    );


    return (
        <Button 
            onPress={() => {
                promptAsync().then((codeResponse) => {
                if (request && codeResponse?.type === 'success' && discovery) {
                    exchangeCodeAsync(
                    {
                        clientId,
                        code: codeResponse.params.code,
                        extraParams: request.codeVerifier
                        ? { code_verifier: request.codeVerifier }
                        : undefined,
                        redirectUri,
                    },
                    discovery,
                    ).then((res) => {                        
                        const provider = new OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
                        const credential = provider.credential({
                            idToken: res.idToken,
                            // accessToken: res.accessToken,
                        });
                        console.log('Credential', credential);

                        // Sign in with the credential
                        signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
                            .then((userCredential) => {
                                // Signed in
                                const user = userCredential.user;
                                console.log('User signed in', user);
                                // ...
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.log('Error signing in', error);
                            });
                    });
                }
                });
            }}
        >
            Sign in with {props.provider_type}
        </Button>
    )
```

Am I doing something wrong?

The token returned by Microsoft appears to be valid JWT. I have found information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989490/use-react-native-firebase-auth-oauth-provider-to-auth-azure-ad-credential) suggesting that Firebase doesn't support Microsoft SSO, which is quite confusing since Microsoft is one of the options available in the Firebase Auth dashboard.